# How to set specific time while using timepicker in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I'm using the [timepicker](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?lnsG0UbP) from jquery and my code looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
 formatTime:'g:i A', 
 format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
 minDate:0,
 minTime:0,
 step:1
});
});
```

After running that I can choose the date and time with the default values set to current time (by using parameters `minDate:0` and `minTime:0`), but the problem is that every next day from today the minimum time is also set to current time... Does anyone of you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: what time you want to display by default ?

Comment: I understand you want the user to be limited to date/time combinations "starting from now"? So that the user cannot select a date/time from the past? If that is so, your options work exactly like that in my enviroment.
I'm using: jQuery v1.11.1, jQuery UI v1.11.2 and jquery-ui-timepicker-addon v1.0.1

Comment: Olav, that works, however if you chose the date in the future, the time earlier than current sill won't be accessible... That's the first issue, the other one is - do you know how to make available only time that starts in e.g. 15 minutes from now?